# browser back button issue after logout in asp.net

Tags: session, asp.net, logout

During website development in asp.net, there's an issue of back button after logout.
I have tried writing the following code, it still doesn't work:

```
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Contents.RemoveAll();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Roles.DeleteCookie();
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
```

On pressing the logout button, I don't want to get back to the previous URL. Help me out pls

Comment: @heavyd i have already tried this, but in this case what happens is it disables the browser's back button from starting of the application. I want to disable it once the user has been logged out.

Comment: You can't  change the caching options on pages other than the current one.  Are you just trying to prevent them from viewing a page again?  They shouldn't be able to perform an actions if they're logged out.  Doing this just smells wrong, I would really reconsider if this is really a requirement.

Comment: Exactly that's the thing. How should i prevent user's from logged out page to enter into previously logged in page by just clicking on the back button?

Comment: disabling back button is not a good approach , you can take the help of session and implement a session for each user , when log out expire the session and and disable all privileges to the site with  out session

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for the browser back button issue.

**Step 1**: Add the following hidden field on your page:

```
<input id="reloadValue" type="hidden" name="reloadValue" value="" />
```

**Step 2**: Add the following code on your page. Note that you should keep any existing `document.ready()` as it is and also add this one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
            $(document).ready(function () {
                     var d = new Date();
                     d = d.getTime();
                     if ($('#reloadValue').val().length == 0) 
                     {
                          $('#reloadValue').val(d);
                          $('body').show();
                     }
                     else 
                     {
                          $('#reloadValue').val('');
                          location.reload();
                     }
            });
</script>
```

Note: This can be done in the master page as well, thus working for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
```

after session abandon redirect to any page with session on it

and session should be like this

```
if (Session["anyhthing"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```